# While loop amount of lines increasement

Tags: java, while-loop

For school I have to make a very simple while loop which reads a number and then prints a piece of text with an extra line. That extra line will be printed as many times as the number in the input.

For example:

Input:

3

Output:

Heb je wel gehoord van de zeven, de zeven,
Heb je wel gehoord van de zevensprong,
Ze zeggen dat ik niet dansen kan,
Ik kan dansen als een edelman
**En dat is 1!**

Heb je wel gehoord van de zeven, de zeven,
Heb je wel gehoord van de zevensprong,
Ze zeggen dat ik niet dansen kan,
Ik kan dansen als een edelman
**En dat is 1!
En dat is 2!**

Heb je wel gehoord van de zeven, de zeven,
Heb je wel gehoord van de zevensprong,
Ze zeggen dat ik niet dansen kan,
Ik kan dansen als een edelman
**En dat is 1!
En dat is 2!
En dat is 3!**

My code until now is:

```
public static void zevensprong(int aantal) {
int count = 1;

while (count <= aantal){
    System.out.println("Heb je wel gehoord van de zeven, de zeven,");
    System.out.println("Heb je wel gehoord van de zevensprong,");
    System.out.println("Ze zeggen dat ik niet dansen kan,");
    System.out.println("Ik kan dansen als een edelman");

    System.out.println("En dat is " + count);
    System.out.println("");
    count++;        

}
```

I may only use while loops in my assignment. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much.

Comment: There needs to be two loops: an outer loop from 1 to `count` to display the "primary" sentence, and within that loop an inner loop to display each `En dat is nnn` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small modification to your code.

```java
int count = 1;
        int printCount=1;
        while (count <= 3){
            System.out.println("Heb je wel gehoord van de zeven, de zeven,");
            System.out.println("Heb je wel gehoord van de zevensprong,");
            System.out.println("Ze zeggen dat ik niet dansen kan,");
            System.out.println("Ik kan dansen als een edelman");
            while(printCount<=count) {
                System.out.println("En dat is " + printCount);
                printCount++;
            }
            printCount=1;
            System.out.println("");
            count++;        

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked and makes it a lot more clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to notice that there are two repetitions: You need to repeat the sentence `n` times and **for each of those repetitions** you need to print "En dat is ##" `n` times. This is what we call a "nested" loop because you need another `while` loop inside of your existing one. This also means you will need a second counter.

Answer (score 1):

Solution requires two loops, outer loop will always print

```
Heb je wel gehoord van de zeven, de zeven, Heb je wel gehoord van de zevensprong, Ze zeggen dat ik niet dansen kan, Ik kan dansen als een edelman
```

inner loop will print

```
En dat is innerloopCounter (innerloopCounter times)
```

Code:

```
public static void zevensprong(int aantal) {
    int outerCounter = 0;
    while (outerCounter++ < aantal){
        System.out.print("Heb je wel gehoord van de zeven, de zeven, Heb je wel gehoord van de zevensprong, ");
        System.out.print(" Ze zeggen dat ik niet dansen kan, Ik kan dansen als een edelman " );
        int innnerCounter = 0;
        while(innnerCounter++ < outerCounter){
           System.out.print("En dat is " + innnerCounter +"! ");

        }
        System.out.println();       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like shown below. Where you'll use another while loop to print `En dat is 1!` given number of times.

```
 public static void zevensprong(int aantal) {
    int count = 1;

    while (count <= aantal){
        System.out.println("Heb je wel gehoord van de zeven, de zeven,");
        System.out.println("Heb je wel gehoord van de zevensprong,");
        System.out.println("Ze zeggen dat ik niet dansen kan,");
        System.out.println("Ik kan dansen als een edelman");

        int val = count;
        int val2 = 1;
        while(val-- > 0 ) {
            System.out.print("En dat is " + val2++);
            System.out.print(". ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        count++;   
    }

}
```